# OpenLayers coordinate system

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I am using a Tile Layer for my map and XYZ for the source of this tile layer in OpenLayers. I am providing PNG files as Z/X/Y. I want to replicate the real world coordinates on my map. The files that i am providing is of a certain country. As they are PNG files they do not have coordinates like open source maps but I want to map the real world and my source. Is it possible to do this in OpenLayers?

Comment: Why do you want to use obsolete OpenLayers 2?

Comment: I did not understand your question

Comment: To put it differently: why do you want to use really old version of OpenLayers 2 (from July 2013), when the last version is 4.6.5 (from March 2017)? Or was tag openlayers-2 added by mistake?

Comment: added by mistake because i cannot find new version tag. sorry

Comment: OK, removed it.

Comment: If I get you right: You try to add a non-georeferenced .png to Openlayers, right? If so, my suggestion is to start by georeferencing the .png file inside QGIS and add it to OpenLayers afterwards. There is a nice tutorial on how to do this in QGIS 3: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/georeferencing_basics.html

Comment: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/static-image.html

Comment: What is relationship (if any) between this question and the following question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/330326/tile-size-remains-the-same-as-default-which-is-256-256-in-openlayers?